# Superscripts after fs - spacing

Tags: superscripts

When certain characters in superscripts follow certain letters ("f" at least) they collide. I'm using a numeric superscripted citation style, but the problem is more general that that as the following MWE demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
f$^6$ f$^1$ y$^6$

f\,$^6$ f\,$^1$ y\,$^6$
\end{document}
```

In the first line, all but the first example look right; in the second line even `f$^6$` looks rather wide, the other superscripts are floating off into the middle distance. This probably applies to `\footnote`s (with letters) as well, I just don't happen to have a combination that demonstrates that.

Can it really be right that for certain combinations I have to add a manual correction (`\kern0.05em` looks about right)? Or is there a more general solution?

[image: output of above code]

Comment: `f\/\textsuperscript{6}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font "knows" the adjustment needed here and makes it available as the italic correction `\/`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
f$^6$ f$^1$ y$^6$

f\textsuperscript6 f\textsuperscript1 y\textsuperscript6 

f\/\textsuperscript{6} f\/\textsuperscript{1} y\/\textsuperscript{6}  $\leftarrow$ this one

f\,$^6$ f\,$^1$ y\,$^6$

f\kern0.05em$^6$ f\kern0.05em$^1$ y\kern0.05em$^6$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It wouldn't have occurred to me to use an *italic* correction in this case! So I should be using `\/\footnote` and `\/\supercite` throughout?

Comment: @ChrisH arguably (and so egreg just argued in chat) that `\textsuperscript` command ought to have applied italic correction always, but it doesn't, so it needs to be added by the user: always applying `\/` (or using your own command that does `\/\textsuperscript` is probably safe, most of the time, for upright fonts it will not add any space, but for some fonts, especially on `f` it may...

Answer (score 6):

Using `f$^6$` is not the best way to cope with this, because it's not math, so

```
f\textsuperscript{6}
```

would be a better way. The problem is that the character “f” slightly extends beyond its bounding box. There is a built-in mechanism for coping with this, the *italic correction* that, despite its name, can come to rescue also for non slanted fonts, which are the ones where the problem presents more often.

Unfortunately, `\textsuperscript` doesn't add the italic correction, which it should, in my opinion. More unfortunately, patching `\textsuperscript` is not sufficient for footnotes.

Let's do a test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
f\textsuperscript{6} f\textsuperscript{1} y\textsuperscript{6}

f\footnote{A}
f\footnote{B}
f\footnote{C}
f\footnote{D}
f\footnote{E}
f\footnote{F}

\setcounter{footnote}{0}

y\footnote{A}
y\footnote{B}
y\footnote{C}
y\footnote{D}
y\footnote{E}
y\footnote{F}

\end{document}
```

that outputs

[image]

Now we patch `\textsuperscript` and `\footnote`; actually a couple of internal macros need to be patched.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@textsuperscript{\/}{}{}
\patchcmd\@footnotemark{\edef}{\/\edef}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
f\textsuperscript{6} f\textsuperscript{1} y\textsuperscript{6}

f\footnote{A}
f\footnote{B}
f\footnote{C}
f\footnote{D}
f\footnote{E}
f\footnote{F}

\setcounter{footnote}{0}

y\footnote{A}
y\footnote{B}
y\footnote{C}
y\footnote{D}
y\footnote{E}
y\footnote{F}

\end{document}
```

and we get

[image]

You can see that the output with `y` is unaffected, while it's improved for `f`, because we essentially add `\/` before `\textsuperscript` and `\footnote`. If the font is properly designed, the italic correction should compensate the right amount of spacing.

A possible patch for `\supercite` is

```
\patchcmd{\mkbibsuperscript}{\unspace}{\unspace\/}{}{}
```

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@textsuperscript{\/}{}{}
\patchcmd\@footnotemark{\edef}{\/\edef}{}{}
\patchcmd{\mkbibsuperscript}{\unspace}{\unspace\/}{}{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{xampl.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

f\supercite{article-full}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, I agree that this feels like it should be internal to the superscripting commands, but I wouldn;t know where to start looking to patch them.  I never actually have a need for bare superscripts in text, so  forgot about `\textsuperscript` in reproducing the effect as minimally as possible.